# User to User Messages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been building messaging in a rails app for users to be able to send each other messages. I've looked at a few gems such as mailboxer but ultimately decided to build my own.

I'm hoping someone can help me put these pieces together. I've been following a similar question's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141564/model-users-message-in-rails-3).

I'm testing in the rails console and I keep getting the following error:

undefined method `send_message' for #

How can I fix this?

**Controller**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    # create a comment and bind it to an article and a user  
    def create
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @sender = current_user
      @message = Message.send_message(@sender, @user)
      flash[:success] = "Message Sent."
      flash[:failure] = "There was an error saving your comment (empty comment or comment way to long)"
    end
end
```

**Routes**

```
  resources :users, :except => [ :create, :new ] do
     resources :store
     resources :messages, :only => [:create, :destroy] 
  end
```

**Messages Model**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :sent, where(:sent => true)
  scope :received, where(:sent => false)

  def send_message(from, recipients)
     recipients.each do |recipient|
       msg = self.clone
       msg.sent = false
       msg.user_id = recipient
       msg.save
     end
     self.update_attributes :user_id => from.id, :sent => true
   end
end
```

Comment: send_message is not a class method, Message need to be instanciated to be able to use `send_message`. Try this `def self.send_message(from, recipients)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking the method on a class level: `Message.send_message`. For this to work, it would expect a declaration like this:

```
def self.send_message(from, recipients)
  # ...
end
```

But, you got this instead:

```
def send_message(from, recipients)
  # ...
end
```

So, either invoke the method on the instance you need it for, or refactor to make it work on a class level.

Comment: Thanks I understand now what I was missing. Now when I test (Message.new.send_message(User.find(1), User.find(2)
) I get a the following error: NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<User:0x007f9d1f402090>

Comment: You are sending only one `User` to your method. You cannot expect to iterate on a single object. Review your code, it's wrong.