# has_many relationship with group

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Message` model with `user_id` and `sender_id` attributes following [model users message in rails 3 question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5861534/471313)

I try to query user conversations based on "sender_id"

I did this

```
  has_many :conversations, :class_name => 'Message', select: [:sender_id], group: [:sender_id]
```

But it only returns the message ID.

```
Message Load (0.8ms)  SELECT sender_id FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY sender_id
=> [#<Message sender_id: 500>]
```

The `select` was used because seems that Postgres requires to explicitly select the attributes to group but If I explicit add them I should be add them in the group clause as well which I don't want.

Any idea how to retrieve messages in a `has_many`association grouped by the `sender_id` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting the `foreign_key` attribute to the column name `sender_id`:

```
has_many :conversations, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
```

Edit: it seems like you're trying to `OR` two columns in your where statement, in which case associations are not appropriate.

Instead, put a method on your user that will return their `conversations`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def conversations
    Message.where("user_id = ? OR sender_id = ?", id, id)
  end

  ...

end
```

Of course you can also set up sent and received messages associations for the user.

Comment: But in this case, the `sender_id` is not the `User`. I should be able to still retrieve messages with `Message.user_id`

Comment: Are you trying to set up an association that has both sent and received messages, so either the `sender_id` or the `user_id` equals the user id? If so grouping is the wrong concept, and I think you're better off creating the two associations for sent and received messages, then creating a scope for `conversations`

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Ok, but back to my question, how are these conversations grouped by the person who sent it? I just want the latest message either sent or received for each user as a conversation.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want - could you update your question with an example of the data you're expecting to be returned? I think grouping might be confusing things since in an active record / sql sense, that's to do with aggregating records.